# Programatically save a PDF in the iPhone

Tags: ios, uiimageview, core-animation, catiledlayer

I'm getting a PDF file in my app like this :

```
NSURL* pdfURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
CGPDFDocumentRef PDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfURL);
CGPDFPageRef PDFPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(PDFDocument, 1);
```

I know that for the images, we can use this method in order to save it in the iPhone :

```
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:uniquePath atomically:YES];
```

But is there a way to write/save the PDF file in the iPhone programatically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one easy way:

```
NSData *myFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your_url"]]; 
[myFile writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"yourfilename.pdf"] atomically:YES];
```

Comment: @Seb It shouldn't. Are you testing this on the simulator? On device you won't be able to write to the bundle resource path. If you have not done it already, the second line should be adjusted to use the application's Documents directory.

Comment: i have used this code and stored it in documents directory.. But wen i open adobe reader app in my iPad, it shows nothing. Y am i not getting any pdf there?

Answer (score -5):

There is no way of saving any data to the iPad memory programmatically except UIImage.

Comment: ok...but this writes the data to the apps bundle directory.Is there a way to save it in iPad memory...like we save uiimage in to library.....?

Comment: What "iPad memory" is for you ?

Comment: @Seb: Frnd. My req is, i need to save my pdf to device in a place where it should be accessible by another PDF app like Adobe Reader.. How can i do that?